# Нельзя обратиться к полям структуры после realloc

Tags: c, realloc

После realloc() нельзя обратиться к полям структуры

Вот, что говорит gdb:

```
(gdb) print flights

$2 = (flight *) 0x8d2220

(gdb) print flights[1]

$3 = {id = 137, quantityPassengers = 3, from = 0x8d22a0 "Anor Londo", target = 0x8d22e0 "London",
  plane = 0x8d2320 "Plane1", relevant = 0 '\000'}

(gdb) print flights[0]

$4 = {id = -1163005939, quantityPassengers = -1163005939,
  from = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>,
  target = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>,
  plane = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>, relevant = 13 '\r'}

...

(gdb) print flights

$5 = (flight *) 0x8d2360
(gdb) print flights[2]

$6 = {id = 5051, quantityPassengers = 18, from = 0x8d2410 "Where", target = 0x8d2450 "None",
  plane = 0x8d2490 "Plane2", relevant = 1 '\001'}

(gdb) print flights[1]

$7 = {id = -1163005939, quantityPassengers = -1163005939,
  from = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>,
  target = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>,
  plane = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>, relevant = 13 '\r'}

(gdb) print flights[0]

$8 = {id = -1163005939, quantityPassengers = -1163005939,
  from = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>,
  target = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>,
  plane = 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00dbaadf00d>, relevant = 13 '\r'}
```

```
flight* FormAndInputFlights(int *n)
{
    int i;
    char END;
    flight *flights = NULL;
    flight *buff = NULL;
    *n = 0;
    do
    {
        buff = flights;
        flights = (flight*)realloc(flights, ((*n)+1) * sizeof(flight));
        if(flights != NULL)
        {
            printf("\n\n\n");
            flights[*n] = FormAndInputFlight();
            printf("\n\n%d | %s\n", flights[*n].id, flights[*n].from);// Это работает
            if(*n > 0)
                printf("\n\n%d | %s\n", flights[(*n)-1].id, flights[(*n)-1].from); //Это не работает
            (*n)++;
            printf("Do you want to continue? (0 = NO and 1 = YES): ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &END);
            END = !END; // =(
        }
        else
        {
            printf(ERRORallocateFlights);
            FreeFlights(&buff, *n);
            END = 1;
        }
    }while(!END);
    return flights; //Если убрать все printf, то тут flights = NULL
}
```

Comment: Конечно, когда такой кривой код. Разве вас не учили, что так `foo = realloc(foo, ...);` делать нельзя?

Comment: Расскажите, тогда, как можно

Comment: `bar = realloc(foo, ...); if (bar == NULL) { printf("Allocation failed!\n"); ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашёл только scanf("%d", &END); - даёт предупреждение на неправильный тип. Поменяйте на "%hhd". Вдруг поможет. Переменная flights - портится.

Comment: Если сделать, как вы сказали, то будет та же проблема

Comment: Вы пробовали? "%d" портит память на 4 байта, у END всего один. Значит bug?

Comment: Я только что пробовал, всё равно на printf крашится

Comment: Тогда точно проблема в `FormAndInputFlight`. Покажите функцию.

Comment: Проблема не в этой функции, ведь как только оттуда вернулось значение, его можно вывести (первый printf), а вот предыдущие нельзя. На следующей итерации можно опять вывести новое значение, но предыдущие нельзя (хотя только что предыдущее выводилось)

Comment: Тогда полностью структуру `flight` и возвращаемый тип это ф-ии `FormAndInputFlight` .

Comment: Прототип функции: flight FormAndInputFlight( void )
Структура:
typedef struct Flight
{
 int id;
 int quantityPassengers;
 char* *from;
 char *target;
 char *plane;
 char relevant; /** F = 0 or T = !F;*/
}flight;